# NetBeans code templates - using current class' name

Tags: templates, netbeans, netbeans-8, code-templates

NetBeans has code templates invoked by typing an abbreviation, and these can use [special codes](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/work_java_code.htm#NBDAG506).

I'd like to have this template:

```
public class GraphTypeManager {
    // This would be created by the template
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GraphTypeManager.class.getName());
```

However, I don't know how to make the template fill in the `GraphTypeManager`, i.e. the currently edited class.

Is there something not mentioned in the docs I could use?